# Elastic Beanstalk Test Environment use copy of production data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, elastic-beanstalk

I have 3 environments using Elastic Beanstalk - Prod, Test, Dev. I want to use a copy of production database in my Test environment.

It seems there's no easy way to "just use a different database". Once that database is being used by the EB environment it pretty much can't be changed, that's what I'm finding. I've tried changing the RDS_* environment variables, but don't see any difference.

So now, it seems the solution I'm looking for is to create a new EB environment using a snapshot of the RDS database that I want to replicate. I have the snapshot, but when I try to create my EB environment using that database I get the error:

DBEngineVersion: Invalid option value: '5.6' (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName: 'DBEngineVersion'): Engine Version 5.6 not supported for postgres db

I'm using 64bit Debian jessie v1.3.1 running Python 3.4 (Preconfigured - Docker) and my application is using Django 1.8. Please let me know any suggestions how I can get around this, or if I am doing something completely wrong.

Comment: Is your snapshot from MySQL RDS instance? You can't restore a snapshot to a different DB engine.

Comment: no i'm using PostgreSQL for the snapshot and for the instance

Comment: Where do you specify PostgreSQL DB engine and version? By default, Elastic Beanstalk use MySQL v5.6.

Comment: I realize this is quite old, but I am trying to do the exact same thing.  did you get this to work? what is your solution?